# Emacs - finding the cursor in multiple windows

Tags: emacs, window, split, cursor

I've started splitting my emacs frame into two side-by-side windows, but often I'm unable to tell at a glance which window the cursor is currently in.  I've bound the other-window command to a special key, so it's easy to hit that -- would there be a way to flash the cursor maybe three times right after switching to the other window?  Or maybe there are better solutions people have thought of?

Comment: Maybe set up your window manager to (better) highlight the currently active window? This is already the default behavior in most window managers I have tried, but some have a default color scheme in which the highlight is barely noticeable.

Comment: He is talking of 'emacs windows', they are not the same as the windows we usually mean. A WM window is an 'emacs frame'. And emacs frames can be split into 'emacs windows' (vertical/horizontal splits).

Answer (score 3):

I find it helps to have emacs highlight the current line. 
The minor mode **hl-line-mode** does that. You can enable it in your current buffer with **M-x** `hl-line-mode`, or globally from your emacs config:

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
```

Take a look at the [Emacswiki: HighlightCurrentLine](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine). It also mentions other minor-modes that might be more in your interest.

---

Edit:

While looking through the wiki myself I found the [crosshairs-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting). I think I'll try it out myself:

```
(crosshairs-mode 1)
(setq col-highlight-vline-face-flag  t
      col-highlight-face             hl-line-face)
```

---

Edit2:

I like the horizontal line, but I find the constant vertical line distracting. Luckily `crosshairs` also provides a flash function `flash-crosshairs` and an idle mode `toggle-crosshairs-when-idle`.

To display the crosshair on idle I have this in my config:

```
(require 'crosshairs)
(toggle-crosshairs-when-idle 1)
(setq col-highlight-vline-face-flag  t
      col-highlight-face             hl-line-face)
```

But this won't flash on buffer/window switches, unfortunately there are no hooks for that. But at least emacs lisp gives us [advising functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions), which allow us to extend existing functions. Though that can be quite tricky.

This will flash the crosshair after buffer switches:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after switch-to-buffer-flash-crosshairs activate)
  "Call `flash-crosshairs' after `switch-to-buffer'"
  (flash-crosshairs))
```

This should work in most cases (when the switch is done without `switch-to-buffer`)

The window switch is more difficult, since minibuffers (open file etc.) cause some issues. So only flash when we switch to another buffer:

```
(defadvice select-window (around select-window-flash-crosshairs activate)
  "Call `flash-crosshairs' after `select-window', if switching to another buffer.
The check is necessary to prevent issues with mini-buffer switching."
  (let (cons (cur-buffer-name (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
             ad-arg-bindings)
    ad-do-it
    (unless (string= (buffer-name (window-buffer window))
                     cur-buffer-name)
      (flash-crosshairs))))
```

`ad-arg-bindings` are the arguments to the advised function and `ad-do-it` executes the original.

To deactivate the advices use:

```
(ad-remove-advice 'select-window 'around 'select-window-flash-crosshairs)
(ad-remove-advice 'switch-to-buffer 'after 'switch-to-buffer-flash-crosshairs)
```

I think that covers most cases, though like I said advising is tricky ...

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an old Emacs package named `e-other-window` and found this question while searching on the net. Finally, I had to dig in my previous computer and found it again, so I just uploaded it on Github to share it to everyone (that's the best backup I can make of it).

https://github.com/N-Mi/e-other-window

> e-other-window.el --- flash windows when you change to them
>
> This is a small usefull Emacs package from Kevin A. Burton that flashes the current window when switching from a window to another using a keybinding.

Combined with **hl-line-mode**, I find it very easy to find where is the cursor in a 2, 3 or 4 windows frame.